# Is there a way to conditionally format border styles in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

The title says it all.

I have some conditional formatting rules, it seems I'm limited to some basic formatting options;

[image: Formatting style]

Is there any workaround to apply further formatting options (such as border)?

Answer (score 4):

One workaround is to use Google Apps Script instead of the built-in conditional formatting options but it doesn't performs so efficiently.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Related

Question with the larger score so far

- [How can I set conditional formatting on a particular cell that depends on another cell's value?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16745/88163)

Question that could be more helpful because it's about conditional formatting borders

- [Conditionally format row borders](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110793/88163)